# Using Inno Setup, Python 3.6.8-32bit, created .exe runs on source computer but not other computers

Tags: python-3.6, inno-setup, 32-bit

I have created a .exe file that runs perfectly on the computer I wrote the scrips on but it won't run on other computers with the following error:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x0003cf8 (most recent call first):
```

1: I have downloaded Python 3.6.8 to the other computer I want to install the .exe on and made sure to select "ADD Python to PATH" option at install. I also checked the Environment Variables System Path to make sure it was added correctly.

2: In Inno Setup I have made sure to include all the files created under the build:

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application. Do not 
use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{AFEEF19B-9CCE-46CB-BE48-03F561834912}
AppName=Order Pro
AppVersion=1.0
;AppVerName=Order Pro 1.0
AppPublisher=AC Mechanical, Inc.
AppPublisherURL=N/A
AppSupportURL=N/A
AppUpdatesURL=N/A
DefaultDirName={autopf}\Order Pro
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
LicenseFile=C:\Users\awilliamson\PycharmProjects\OrderPro\build\exe.win32- 
3.6\legal\README.md
; Uncomment the following line to run in non administrative install mode 
(install for current user only.)
;PrivilegesRequired=lowest
OutputDir=C:\Users\awilliamson\Desktop
OutputBaseFilename=Order Pro installer
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
WizardStyle=modern

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\awilliamson\PycharmProjects\OrderPro\build\exe.win32-3.6\OrderPro.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\awilliamson\PycharmProjects\OrderPro\build\exe.win32-3.6\python36.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\awilliamson\PycharmProjects\OrderPro\build\exe.win32-3.6\data\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs;  Permissions: users-modify
Source: "C:\Users\awilliamson\PycharmProjects\OrderPro\build\exe.win32-3.6\images\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "C:\Users\awilliamson\PycharmProjects\OrderPro\build\exe.win32-3.6\legal\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "C:\Users\awilliamson\PycharmProjects\OrderPro\build\exe.win32-3.6\lib\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "C:\Users\awilliamson\PycharmProjects\OrderPro\build\exe.win32-3.6\tcl\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "C:\Users\awilliamson\PycharmProjects\OrderPro\build\exe.win32-3.6\tk\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "C:\Users\awilliamson\PycharmProjects\OrderPro\build\exe.win32-3.6\lib\encodings\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{autoprograms}\Order Pro"; Filename: "{app}\OrderPro.exe"
Name: "{autodesktop}\Order Pro"; Filename: "{app}\OrderPro.exe"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\OrderPro.exe"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,Order Pro}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

3: I have read the following thread:

The core reason is quite simple: Python does not find its modules directory, so it can of course not load encodings, too

Python doc on embedding says "Py_Initialize() calculates the module search path based upon its best guess" ... "In particular, it looks for a directory named lib/pythonX.Y"

Yet, if the modules are installed in (just) lib - relative to the python binary - above guess is wrong.

Although docs says that PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH are regarded, we observed that this was not the case; their actual presence or content was completely irrelevant.

The only thing that had an effect was a call to Py_SetPath() with e.g. [path-to]\lib as argument before Py_Initialize().

Sure this is only an option for an embedding scenario where one has direct access and control over the code; with a ready-made solution, special steps may be necessary to solve the issue.

I do not understand what file to edit to change where Py_Initialize() looks for the 'encodings' file. In a cmd prompt? '**init**' file? Inno Setup? I am confused because the .exe runs fine and can find 'encodings' on the source computer and not other computers. I have inspected the resulting install files and they are similar. Is there a way to modify Py_Initalize() to be able to locate 'encodings'?

Comment: If you simply copy the .exe to the target machine (without using Inno Setup), does it work?

Comment: I tried that but when it runs it gives the 'Fatal Python Error'

Comment: Basically, you need to figure out what's different between the computer that works and the one that doesn't work. (Something is obviously different.) We can't answer that question for you. Once you find out the correct way to get it to work, _then_ you can automate with an installer.

Comment: Yes, if the program does not work for you even when deployed manually, then you have asked a wrong question. Because your problem has nothing to do with Inno Setup. Now you are seemingly asking a question the requires both Python and Inno Setup knowledge. While your problem seems to be Python-only. So you scare away Python experts by your emphasis on Inno Setup.